# What is the containing module of PyHANDLE in win32?

Tags: python, winapi

I've been working with win32 in Python standard library when I came across PyHANDLE objects but I couldn't to find its module for annotation purposes. Does anyone know its module?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that my answer is correct, but it might be out of context. You are saying that you " came across `PyHANDLE` objects" but you didn't add a reference. Can you please add links or examples to the places where you came across it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/wuxc/pywin32doc/blob/master/md/PyHANDLE.md) of `pywin32`, `PyHANDLE` is and object of type `pywintypes.HANDLE`.

> PyHANDLE Object
> A Python object, representing a win32 HANDLE.

> Comments
> This object wraps a win32 HANDLE object, automatically closing it when the object
> is destroyed. To guarantee cleanup, you can call either PyHANDLE::Close, or
> win32api::CloseHandle.
> Most functions which accept a handle object also accept an integer - however,
> use of the handle object is encouraged.

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538976/python-pyhandle-object-in-win32gui) quatutes the above documentation.

The following [documentation page](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pywintypes__HANDLE_meth.html) shows how to create the `PyHANDLE` object (but misses the import statement).

---

Example for creating `PyHANDLE` object (including the import statement):

```
import pywintypes

PyHANDLE = pywintypes.HANDLE()
```

---

It seems that `PyHANDLE` is a naming convention for an object of type `pywintypes.HANDLE()`.

I suppose the true use case is for wrapping an Windows handle that returned as an integer.

Example:

```
import pywintypes
import win32gui
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.imshow('window', np.zeros((100, 100), np.uint8))

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "window")  # Return handle as an integer

PyHANDLE = pywintypes.HANDLE(hwnd)  # Wrap the integer with HANDLE object
```