# Can't find module, which contains PyHANDLE for type annotation

Tags: python, pywin32

I wanted to find a type of value, returning by `win32file.CreateFile()` in python. From [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76457304/what-is-the-containing-module-of-pyhandle-in-win32) i learned that it must be a `pywintypes.HANDLE` object.

But i sill got "cannot find reference" warning when i try to annotate my handle object like that:

```
import pywintypes
import win32file

handle: pywintypes.HANDLE

handle = win32file.CreateFile(args)
```

So, how to annotate this variable correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post which you mentioned, was this example:

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "window")  # Return handle as an integer

PyHANDLE = pywintypes.HANDLE(hwnd)
```

In your case, you just annotated variable. I don't know what you want to do, but if you want to use pywintypes like in the post, you may to try this:

```
import pywintypes
import win32file


win32_created_file = win32file.CreateFile(args)
handle: pywintypes.HANDLE = pywintypes.HANDLE(win32_created_file)
```